# Get specific Range to Export

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, export-to-pdf

can anyone help me with my problem?
Need to export a specific range (A1:J39), not the full sheet.

```
function SavePDFtoDrive() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ltrsht = ss.getSheetByName("Schichtübergabe-Protokoll");
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Daten");
  var sheets=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for(var i =0;i<sheets.length;i++){
    if(sheets[i].getName()!="Schichtübergabe-Protokoll"){ sheets[i].hideSheet() }
    }
    var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId());
    var theBlob = pdf.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(datasheet.getRange("I8").getValue()+".pdf");
    var folderID = "1dyKFNvQWrSiNFA8N5PyUMPJQpWSVhsLf"; // Folder id to save in a folder
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
    var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);
}
```

Comment: And i need export options/settings... landscape and perfect fit width

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*Rather than getting your blob using `DriveApp`, you can obtain your blob from an export URL using `UrlFetchApp`.*

#### More Information:

When you use `DriveApp` to create a blob of a file, it doesn't have the functionality to read the specifics of the file. In this case, you can't specify the range of a Sheet you wish to export with `DriveApp`.

You can, however, build a URL with all your export parameters and create your export in Drive by creating a blob of the response and creating it in Drive.

#### Code:

```js
function SavePDFtoDrive() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ltrsht = ss.getSheetByName("Schichtübergabe-Protokoll");
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Daten");
  
  // build your URL:  
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ss.getId() + "/export?"
  //define your parameters:
  var params = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
  + '&portrait=false'
  + '&fitw=true'
  + '&gid=' + ltrsht.getSheetId()
  + '&range=A1:J39';
   
  //get token for UrlFetch:
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(); 
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + params, { 
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    }
  });  
  
  var fileName = datasheet.getRange("I8").getValue() + ".pdf";
  var theBlob = response.getBlob().setName(fileName);
  var folderID = "1Hp-P1dzWaKHhhS2FTPzKib6pwJibS12t";
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  
  folder.createFile(theBlob);
}
```

#### References:

- [Class `UrlFetchApp` | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

---

#### Related Questions/Answers:

- [how to print a long Google sheets column in fewer columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60059929/how-to-print-a-long-goggle-sheets-column-in-fewer-columns/60061751#60061751)

Comment: I need one more option/setting.... Edges narrow. Can you tell me the code for it pls ?